# how to remove display none the anchor tag in li inside div by Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div which contains many `li` elements. But I want to display none of the anchor tags which has input checkbox with `value = "1"`.

See the screenshot:
[image]

Code that I have tried (not working)

```
  $("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').closest("a")
```

Comment: Try $("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').closest("a").hide() or $("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').parent().hide()

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').parents("a").hide();`

```js
$("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').parents("a").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example_columns">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1"> a
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <input type="checkbox" value="0"> b
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.show()` after your selector and it should work.

```
$("#example_columns").find('input[value="1"]').closest("a").show();
```

Comment: if they want to `display none` then wouldn't they want to hide the element, not show it?